# Redirigir a url enviando parámetros por post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

tengo un menú el cual redirige a diferentes `url` una de ellas es un proyecto distinto pero dentro de un mismo dominio.

*Proyecto principal (miDominio.com.mx/MenuApps/Index)*

**Menú**

```
//mas código como este
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
  <div class="contact-box">
    <!-- /Nuevo se sustituye por /BuzonFiscal -->
    <a href="#">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="text-center">
          <img alt="image" class="m-t-xs img-responsive" src="~/img/admix_logo_colibri.png">
          <div class="m-t-xs font-bold">Buzon Fiscal</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
//mas código como este
```

en el `script` tengo esto donde hago mi peticion `ajax`

```
$.ajax({
  data:  "Dato_en_MD5",
  url:   '/BuzonFiscal',
  type:  'post',
  success:  function (response) {
    console.log(response)
  }
});
```

Hasta donde entiendo este `ajax` no hará el direccionamiento a la `url`, lo que necesito es redireccionar y enviar los datos ocultos.

*Buzón Fiscal (miDominio.com.mx/BuzonFiscal)*

este es el **controlador del buzón fiscal**:

```
namespace Emisiones.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Empresas(string dato_en_MD5)
        {
            //.. lo que tenga que hacer 
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Entonces **¿Como puedo redirigir a `miDominio.com.mx/BuzonFiscal` enviando dos datos por `post`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para enviar dos o mas datos puedes serializarlos en formato json y recibirlos en el Controller leyendo el contenido de la petición:

Petición:

```
$.ajax({
    data = JSON.stringify({ dato1: 'Dato_en_MD5_1', dato2: 'Dato_en_MD5_2' }),
    url: '/BuzonFiscal',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
    }
});
```

Controller acompañado de una clase para deserializar a esa clase:

```
namespace Emisiones.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Empresas()
        {
            var request = Request.InputStream;
            var json = new StreamReader(request).ReadToEnd();
            Datos datos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datos>(json);
            //.. lo que tenga que hacer 
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Clase `Datos`:

```
public class Datos
{
    public string dato1 { get; set; }
    public string dato2 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

por que no haces una peticion post desde el html?

```
<form id='peticionPost' action="tu_url" method="post"> 
  <input type="hidden" id="md5 "name="md5" value="valor_md5">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

desde tu JS cargas el valor al input oculto y envias el formulario post.

```
$('#md5').val('tu_md5');
$('peticionPost').submit();
```